# Components don't load on first view when called from Service

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-components

We are implementing our first component which loads from a service and it works although the data is never visible when we first load the page. After a full refresh of the page we need to view this component (loads blank), navigate to another, and when we return the data loads fine. Can anyone shed some light on what we are doing wrong?

Here is the component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { StbBaseComponent } from './StbBaseComponent';
import { IRegion } from './region.component';
import { RegionService } from '../services/region.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'region-list',
    templateUrl: './regionlist.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./regionlist.component.less']
})
export class RegionListComponent extends StbBaseComponent implements OnInit {
    public regions: IRegion[];
    public selectedRegion: IRegion;

    constructor(private regionService: RegionService) {
        super();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getRegions();
    }

    onSelect(region: IRegion): void {
        this.selectedRegion = region;
    }

    getRegions(): void {
        this.regionService.getRegions().subscribe(regions => this.regions = regions);
    }
}
```

Here is the service implementation

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';

import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { IRegion } from '../components/region.component';

@Injectable()
export class RegionService {
    private baseServiceUrl: string;
    private fetchedRegions: IRegion[];

    constructor(private http: Http,
        @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string)
    { this.baseServiceUrl = baseUrl }

    getRegions(): Observable<IRegion[]> {
        var url = this.baseServiceUrl + 'api/realm/regions';

        this.http.get(url).subscribe(result => {
            this.fetchedRegions = result.json() as IRegion[];
            console.log('regions called. count:' + this.fetchedRegions.length);
        }, error => {
            console.error(error)
        });

        return of(this.fetchedRegions);
    }
}
```

The link we use to access the component is

```
<li [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']">
    <a [routerLink]="['/regions']">
        Regions
    </a>
</li>
```

Here is the `NgModule` configuration

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NavMenuComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        RegionListComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        HttpModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'regions', component: RegionListComponent },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
        ])
    ],
    providers: [RegionService]
})
```

Comment: `this.http.get(url).subscribe` is an asynchronous operation,  `return of(this.fetchedRegions);` won't return what you're expecting

Comment: You should not add 'subscribe()' in the service call. Just return the json in '.map()'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RRForUI has explained about what's wrong with your code,

You need to make the following changes,

**RegionService:**

```
getRegions(): Observable<IRegion[]> {
    var url = this.baseServiceUrl + 'api/realm/regions';
    return this.http.get(url).map((res: Response) => res.json());
}
```

And in your component,

```
getRegions(): void {
    this.regionService.getRegions().subscribe(regions => this.regions = regions);
}
```

---

**PS**: Always prefer using [`HttpClient`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient) instead of [`Http`](https://angular.io/api/http/Http), which is going to deprecated.

Using `HttpClient` your code becomes much simpler,

`return this.http.get<IRegion[]>(url);`

Answer (score 1):

What I think happening here is
1) You are subscribing in the service call which is async operation and returning `this.fetchedRegions` which will be blank. Hence there is no data to show when the page is loaded as there is no delay at all
2) Next, when you navigate to another route and come back, this.fetchedRegions is resolved hence you see the data.

replace subscribe from the service with map and dont return this.fetchedRegions. Subscription in component should take care of resolving the http call